# How do I keep script from runing multiple times

Tags: jquery, volusion

Here is my code that my program appends to each of my orders.  I need it to only run once. I have tried tips from other similar posts but it doesn't work with my code for some reason

```
<script language="javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    jQuery(function (){
        var product_code;
        jQuery('td[width="12%"][align="left"]').before('<td><b>Image</b></td>');    
        jQuery('td[width="7%"][align="right"]').remove();
        jQuery('td[width="8%"][align="right"]').remove();
        jQuery('td[width="12%"][valign="top"]').each(function(){
            product_code = jQuery.trim(jQuery(this).text());
            var product_code_fix = product_code.replace(/\//g, "-fslash-");
            jQuery(this).before('<td width="12%" valign="TOP" bgcolor="#f9f9f9"><img border="0" alt="' + product_code + '" title="' + product_code + '" src="/v/vspfiles/photos/' + product_code_fix + '-0.jpg"></td>');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you give a bit more information about what the behavior is from this script running more than once?

Comment: due to volusion software the script is inseted at end of each order.  to print it appends each order all into one page which means the script is listed multiple times pr page

Comment: People, don't be so quick to down vote just because you may not understand the context in which they are asking a question. This is specific to Volusion using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

What the OP is asking about is a script which adds in the product image on a packing slip when an admin prints the customers order. The code above was not written to add the images to packing slips via batch printing thus that is why the OP is getting the script running as many times as he has orders in the batch.

You just need to setup a simple flag to stop this.

```
<script language="javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
if (typeof runcheck === 'undefined'){
    var runcheck ='run';
    $(function (){
        var product_code;
        var product_code_fix;
        $('td[width="12%"][align="left"]').before('<td><b>Image</b></td>');
        $('td[width="7%"][align="right"]').remove();
        $('td[width="8%"][align="right"]').remove();
        $('td[width="12%"][valign="top"]').each(function(){
            product_code = $.trim($(this).text());
            product_code_fix = product_code.replace(/\//g, "-fslash-");
            $(this).before('<td width="12%" valign="TOP" bgcolor="#f9f9f9"><img border="0" alt="' + product_code + '" title="' + product_code + '" src="/v/vspfiles/photos/' + product_code_fix + '-0.jpg"></td>');
            $('img').error(function(){$(this).hide();});
        });
    });
}
```